# NCPDP D.0 integration using mirth Connect

Tags: mirth

Need NCPDP D.0 examples, i am working on a project in which i am using mirth connect interface but i need NCPDP D.0 message examples .

If you can help that will appreciate lot.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can somone answer this please ? . Help will be greatly appreciated as i am not getting more help on NCPDP D.0 in google.

Comment: Is there a formal spec for NCPDP messages, no examples there?

Comment: I was able to figure out NCPDP D.0 example below given.  121212DØE123232323bb1Ø14563663bbbbbbbb2ØØ7Ø91598765bbbbb<1E><1C>AMØ1<1C>C41962Ø615<1C>C51<1C>CAJO
SEPH<1C>CBSMITH<1C>CM123 MAIN STREET<1C>CNMY TOWN<1C>COCO<1C>CP34567<1C>C71<1E><1C>AMØ4<1C>C21234
56789     But i am not sure how i can use Mirth interface to build this type of message while i am taking data from database . I need help in mirth regarding how can we create a channel that can write message in above format in which there <1C>  as field seprator after each field and <1E> is segment seprator after each segment.Thanks in Advanve.

Comment: Adding a hex to a string in JavaScript is a question different from what you originally asked.

Comment: You are correct !!.  Sorry for that but earlier i was not able to get ncpdp D.0 example after that i got it from google but i need help now creating this type of ncpdp message using mirth connect . If you could help , i appreciate it. Thanks in advance. !!

Comment: You may try "[Unofficial Mirth Connect Developer's Guide](http://mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com)" (however it's about HL7 messages, not NCPDP) or create a job request on sites such as elance.